# Keep or remove nscd?

Tags: security, debian

Updated question:

Assuming the setup of a "minimal" web server (apache2, php) - e.g. with the least features possible - I would like to know if the nscd is truly required for optimal functioning of the machine.

Comment: updated to clarify "minimal". downvoter can you please justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of "minimal server" you are intending to build, so I can't give you a good *answer*.
I can, however, offer you these *guidelines*.

The `name service caching daemon` is a caching daemon. The data it caches is available by other means.

How useful a cache is depends on:

- how often you query what it holds
- how often what it holds is out of date (and how much that matters)
- how often you cannot connect to the main data-source (and how much that matters)
- how much more efficient (memory, time, load) it is to access the cache than the primary data-source